# Batch file to copy and rename files

Tags: vba, powershell, batch-file, scripting, cmd

I have an excel file which I need to copy multiple times (103, to be specific) and these new files need to be renamed based on a text file. For example, 63100_attachment.xls is the file to be copied and the new files would for example have the following names (which I already listed in a separate excel file, I can also save this in a text file):

```
63126_attachment.xls
63283_attachment.xls
63284_attachment.xls
63285_attachment.xls
63299_attachment.xls
63300_attachment.xls
63301_attachment.xls
63326_attachment.xls
63327_attachment.xls
63328_attachment.xls
63348_attachment.xls
63349_attachment.xls
63350_attachment.xls
63351_attachment.xls
63352_attachment.xls
63439_attachment.xls
63440_attachment.xls
63441_attachment.xls...
```

The numbers before the '_attachment' string are not incremental and would really need to be based on the list. Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (listfile.txt) do copy "63100_attachment.xls" "%%a"
```

That is, as a line in a batch file. Reduce `%%a` to `%a` to operate from the prompt. Add `>nul` to suppress messages. Change `copy` to `ECHO copy` to see the proposed actions rather than executing them.

Comment: As it should be, so if you'd just click the big open tick next to the question, it's marked solved and points are awarded

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub batch_rename()

On Error GoTo errHndl

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder
Dim sourcePath As String, destPath As String
Dim sourceFile As String, destFile As String, sourceExtension As String
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, row As Range

sourcePath = "\path to old files\"
destPath = "\path to new files\"
sourceFile = ""
destFile = ""
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "B10")

For Each row In rng.Rows
    sourceExtension = Split(Trim(row.Cells(, 2)), ".")(1)
    sourceFile = sourcePath + Trim(row.Cells(, 2))
    destFile = destPath + Trim(row.Cells(, 1)) + "." + sourceExtension
    fso.CopyFile sourceFile, destFile, False
Next row

MsgBox "Yay! Operation was successful.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Done"
Exit Sub


errHndl:
    MsgBox "Error happened while working on: " + vbCrLf + _
        sourceFile + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + "Error " + _
        Str(Err.Number) + ": " + Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```